# Android View Animation between activity transition

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, activity-transition

How can i keep an animation alive while the transitions between activities are occurring?

Suppose that i have two activities A and B. Activity B has a "slide in" transition over the activity A. I want to keep a button rotating in my activity A while the transition of B is occurring. My button stop the rotating animation when the Activity B starts the slide over the activity A. I guess it happens because the android switch the UI Thread process to the new activity that is coming and stop what the previous activity was doing, but in my case the user still can see the activity A being covered by the activity B.

Comment: after the transition, the activity A can still be seen? Have you try fragment?

Comment: The transition has 500 milliseconds to occur which is the @android:integer/config_longAnimTime. After the transition the Activity A can't be seen because it is covered by Activity B. My problem is while the transition is occurring, my animation is running in Activity A and when the first pixel of Activity B run over the Activity A the animation stops.

Comment: I think fragment is the simply way to do that.

Comment: I want the same behavior. on Android 9.0 I am able to get this behavior but not on previous APIs. Did you find any solution other than using fragment?.

Comment: Hi @SAIR I did not as I stopped doing this a long time ago but Fragment seems to be the proper one.