# View animations getting stopped by activity transition

Tags: android, transition, android-transitions

I'm building an app launcher and am exploring new app launch animations. I just ran into an issue that occurs when trying to run a view animation (using `view.animate()`) while launching a 3rd party activity. I've attached two videos below to demonstrate the problem:

**1. Intended animation:**

[image]

As you can see, the background scales up while the home screen UI scales down and it runs pretty smoothly!

**2. Here's what happens when you launch an app at the same time:**

[image]

As you can see in the above GIF, the animation just kinda jerks forward and then gets stuck, while the app launch animation runs perfectly well.

My goal is to 'combine' the two animations smoothly to create a similar effect as the app launch animations on iOS 11. It seems like maybe there should be a way to force the UI thread to keep running until the activity has disappeared completely.

Is this actually possible, or am I just crazy? Any help is appreciated!

(Similar question for reference: [Android View Animation between activity transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42080009/android-view-animation-between-activity-transition))

Comment: Pust some code as well let us see what you have done so far so that we can help you with this

Comment: @AkshayKatariya There is nothing specific. Like I said, I&amp;#39;m using `.animate()` to scale up/down the views and, of course, I'm using `overridePendingTransition()` for the activity transitions. Nothing fancy